# How can I use post data and json in ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ht...y.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"User=A&Pass=1"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
NSData* data2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: notyURL];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data2 waitUntilDone:YES];});
```

How can I get dispatch_async to use data rather than data2?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `sendSynchronousRequest` and `dispatch_async`, I suggest using the NSURLConnection class method `sendAsynchronousRequest`, like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

}];
```